# "The library is neither a target nor built/installed properly"

Tags: ros, catkin, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Hello I have a package called wp3_driver_pkg which builds without errors when I build it alone but when I'm trying to use it in another package (ur10) I have the following error :

```
  Project 'ur10' tried to find library 'wp3_driver_pkg'.  The library is
  neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project
  'wp3_driver_pkg'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory
  containing its code is included?
```

The package wp3_driver_pkg has been added to the  ur10 package.xml for build and run.
and is called  in the cmakefile.txt of the ur10:

```
find_package( wp3_driver_pkg REQUIRED)
```

This is the catkin_package() in the cmakefile.txt for the wp3_driver_pkg

```
catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include
LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME} wp3_driver_lib
CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime roscpp rospy roslib ${MSG_DEPS}
)
```

the wp3_driver_lib is a library added in the same cmakefile with the source file

```
 add_library(wp3_driver_lib
         src/wp3_driver.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(wp3_driver_lib
        ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

I can even see the package being built before in the terminal :
[image: image description]

And if I use the command "rospack fin wp3_driver_pkg" just after the failed compilation and the package is found, even if I suppress the devel and build folder of the workspace.

Thanks for the answers  if you see what I'm doing wrong !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237183/%22the-library-is---neither-a-target-nor-built/installed-properly%22/) by [sumperfees](https://answers.ros.org/users/27042/sumperfees/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-06-16

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to export a hypotetical library called ${PROJECT_NAME}.
In your case it looks you don't have any target or library called ${PROJECT_NAME}. Instead, in your case you only have to export the library "wp3_driver_lib" that is the only artifact that really exits.

```
catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include
LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME} wp3_driver_lib
CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime roscpp rospy roslib ${MSG_DEPS}
)
```

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2016-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moatilliatta](https://answers.ros.org/users/28244/moatilliatta/) on 2016-10-13**:
I don't understand your answer. I have a similiar problem and I did it like you quoted it. But the proplem persists. Is there another command how to export the library?

**Comment by [bluenote](https://answers.ros.org/users/37779/bluenote/) on 2019-01-16**:
Me neither. Isn't the code snippet posted in your answer exactly the same as the one in the question? What has to be changed?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2019-03-29**:
I had to remove the LIBRARIES line entirely, I wasn't building anything named `${PROJECT_NAME}` (or building anything conventionally at all, just messages for _msgs style package).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was getting the same kind of errors. After stripping the problem down to a very basic setup I found out that for some reason catkin doesn't like catkin_package being **after** add_library. If it is, you get these kind of errors.

```
add_library(a_library_name)
catkin_package(LIBRARIES a_library_name) # WRONG
```

---

```
catkin_package(LIBRARIES a_library_name) # CORRECT
add_library(a_library_name)
```

---

Originally posted by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) with karma: 257 on 2018-06-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tal](https://answers.ros.org/users/11486/tal/) on 2018-11-08**:
I had the same problem, and this is the actually the correct answer.
The order does matter.

**Comment by [luna wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/90459/luna-wu/) on 2021-12-01**:
Excuse me, under which file did you change it?

**Comment by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) on 2021-12-09**:
This is about the package's CMakeLists.txt

**Comment by [luna wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/90459/luna-wu/) on 2021-12-09**:
Thanks, I tried, but still can't solve the problems